# Clocks of two stationary inertial frames

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames

I am trying to prove Lorentz transformations using only the second postulate of Special Relativity. My proof makes use of the following fact:

"If two inertial frames (S and S') have no relative motion, then in both frames clocks tick at the same pace, and x'=x-d, where d is the distance of the origin of S' from S."

Is this a necessary postulate of special relativity? Or it can be proven somehow? Or is it a consequence of the definition of inertial systems?

I know that this is an obvious fact if we set u=0 in Lorentz transforms, but I'm asking if it is a needed assumption to prove Lorentz transformations.

Comment: This is true with or without SR. since it has nothing to do with c constant.

Comment: Why is it true? How do you deduce that?

Comment: so how do you decide if two clocks tick the same? take your watch  at work and one at home for example .